# Python: Is there any issue with using __getattribute__ within a class?

Tags: python, double-underscore

I have created a class for managing subscriptions to a messaging service. The class instantiates three separate clients for reasons related to the configuration for each subscription, also three per instance of the class. To reduce the instantiation of the three clients to one for loop, I've used `__getattribute__` and `__setattr__`. I've read other threads about these methods, and I'm not sure if using them as I have could lead to issues. Here is a very simplified example:

```
class BaseClient(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        
    def connect(self):
        return 'client logged on'
        
    def do_other_things(self):
        return 'other things done'
        
    

class MsgServiceListener(object):
    
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.client1 = None
        self.client2 = None
        self.client3 = None
        self.clientNames = ['client1', 'client2', 'client3']
        
    def createAndSubscribe(self):
        for client in self.clientNames:
            if not self.__getattribute__(client):
                self.__setattr__(client, BaseClient(client))
                self.__getattribute__(client).connect()
                self.__getattribute__(client).do_other_things()
```

Is there anything wrong with the way I've harnessed the underscore methods?

Comment: This belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com, not here.

Comment: why exactly would this belong on codereview?

Comment: You don't have a technical problem that needs solving. You're just asking for us to review your code, and provide criticisms/tips/feedback, such as "Is there anything wrong with the way I've harnessed the underscore methods?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the dunder methods `__setattr__`/`__getattr__` (or `__getattribute__`), you should use `getattr(self, client)` and `setattr(self, client, value)`...

but better yet, you should just use a dict if you need to map names to objects.

```
class MsgServiceListener:
    def __init__(self):
        self.clients = {}
        self.clientNames = ["client1", "client2", "client3"]

    def createAndSubscribe(self):
        for client in self.clientNames:
            self.clients[client] = c = BaseClient(client)
            c.connect()
            c.do_other_things()
```